# Use a configuration file from the host when building a Docker image

Tags: tomcat, docker

I am trying to build one image for tomcat server via docker file. When building it, i would like to copy a configuration file say users.xml from the current host directory to the tomcat image built.

I would like to know whether what i am trying to do makes sense and if yes, how do i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying files from the host into the image during the build makes sense, yes.

You don't say what you've tried so far, but you can use the `ADD` and `COPY`instructions in your **Dockerfile** to add your *users.xml* configuration file to the image. Have a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add).

Just make sure everything is clear : when adding/copying files during build, these files must be on the host where you ran the `docker build` command, which may be different from the the host where the Docker server runs.

Also, the file to copy/add must be in the directory containing the **Dockerfile**, or inside a sub-directory, but cannot be located in any upper-level directory.

Note that the `ADD` command also lets you insert files from an external source (http(s)).

Comment: a frequent pitfall is also to try to ADD/COPY a file from the host which is *outside* the directory containing the Dockerfile

Comment: Yes, makes sense to add this 'detail' - updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.20-jre8
ADD server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf
COPY /target/webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

I was adding this customised server.XML to replace the TOMCAT native server.xml